# Any possible trick or technique to read third party cookies in IE11 on windows 10

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, single-sign-on, windows-10, p3p

Microsoft has removed P3P policy, through this we can read and create third party cookie in IE on windows 8.1 and earlier. But after removing this we can't create or read third party cookies.

We have on centralize system for authentication on http://a.com  and we create cookies on http://a.com when user get login on http://b.com or http://c.com through JSONP request and read cookies always from http://a.com for checking user is loggedin or not and we share session across all our websites by this technique. But now it is not working in IE11 on windows 10 because we can't create cookies when use get logged in and can't read cookies on other site.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? I'd be happy to elaborate if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, server `A` (http://a.com) always knows whether the user is logged in or not.

You should be able to query `A` to get the authentication state from a page hosted on another domain using AJAX. This is not permitted by default in order to prevent [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), but you can allow it by configuring `A` to include [CORS headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) in each HTTP response.

Comment: Sorry Martin for delayed response, Calling Ajax is possible but IE10 and IE11 on windows 10 doesn't send cookie of A domain in in Ajax request

Comment: The browser should send the cookies if the domain, protocol (https/http) and port are identical. Do you get an error in the browser?

Comment: When I am accessing cookies on server side, getting null!